# Não consigo pegar valor do data-object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tem o seguinte problema tenho vários inputs listados com a mesma classe css, porém preciso pegar um data-atributte de cada um ao clicar no respectivo input para pegar o seu valor do atributter:

**Por exemplo**

```
<input type="button" data-object="{"nome": "Fulano"}" class="btn btn-primary"/>
<input type="button" data-object="{"nome": "Maria"}" class="btn btn-primary"/>
<input type="button" data-object="{"nome": "José"}" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

Comment: Você realmente precisa armazenar um objeto completo no html? Acredito que seja mais vantajoso semente a referência a ele.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de tudo reveja o HTML, veja a "hierarquia" das aspas duplas, você as abre e fecha de maneira errada...
Depois tente o seguinte:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".btn-primary").on('click', function(){
      alert(JSON.parse($(this).attr('data-object')).nome);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" data-object='{"nome": "Fulano"}' class="btn btn-primary"/>
<input type="button" data-object='{"nome": "Maria"}' class="btn btn-primary"/>
<input type="button" data-object='{"nome": "José"}' class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

Comment: Vlw cara funcionou perfeitamente.